# Probability without replacement in forming a committee

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

In order to pick members for forming a committee, 4 names are randomly drawn from a jar (one by one, without replacement) containing the names of 10 experts. Of the 10 experts, there is one individual, say A, who can play an important role in the committee. What is the probability that individual A will not get picked for the committee role?

a. $0.1$
b. $0.3$
c. $0.4$
d. $0.6$

Here, out of 10 people, the probability of selection without a replacement is equal to  ${10 \choose 1}$${9\choose 1}$${8\choose 1}$${7 \choose 1}$. How do I approach after that? Can anyone explain how to solve this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I would suggest using combinations here. True it says names drawn one after the other, but the event whose probability is asked does not depend on the order in which the names are drawn.

Comment: Hi, I have used combination here, but I don't know how to approach it further. Can you help me out in this?

Comment: ${10 \choose 1}{9 \choose 1}{8 \choose 1}{7 \choose 1}=5040$ is not a probability. Nor is ${10 \choose 4}=210$ but it might be more useful here

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is not a probability, but I have no idea how to proceed further using the same. Its kinda confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new, and have made some sort of effort, please learn a few things

- choosing without replacement $\equiv$  *hypergeometric distribution*
- whether you choose one by one or all together, it's the same.
- when you talk of *choosing* order doesn't matter, so just use $^nC_r$

*Hint*

Now total possible choices are obviously $^{10}C_4$, and this will form the denominator. Now suppose you are the "special" person and you aren't chosen. What should be the numerator ?

> The numerator should be $^9C_4$, shouldn't it ?

But in such a simple case, an easier way exists

> Since $4$ out of $10$ are chosen, the probability that any particular person is not chosen is simply $\frac{6}{10}$